# Why does the Java App lose connection after MongoDB restarted?

Tags: java, apache, mongodb, database-connection

The MongoDB is in a replica set with three members. Sometimes one or two MongoDB instances restarted, the Java Apps lose connection and show the following error and then I have to restart the Java Apps manually so as to re-connect the MongoDB replica set:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: 
Unable to connect to any server that matches 
{serverSelectors=[ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=secondaryPreferred}, 
LatencyMinimizingServerSelector{acceptableLatencyDifference=15 ms}]}; 
nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoServerSelectionException: 
Unable to connect to any server that matches 
{serverSelectors=[ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=secondaryPreferred}, 
LatencyMinimizingServerSelector{acceptableLatencyDifference=15 ms}]}
```

I would like to know are there any solutions to keep the connectivity even if the MongoDB instances restarted? Thank you so much.

Comment: Did you provide all the 3 servers in your connection string?

Comment: @yaoxing yes sure, i use spring data to config the replica set

Comment: Could you post your configuration? Especially the ``socketTimeout``,...

Comment: That is not the behavior I would expect.  The replica set monitor is designed to re-connect as soon as the servers become available again. What version of Spring Data MongoDB are you using?  How long did you wait before restarting?  Did you restart the MongoDB instances one at a time?  Can you post the full stack trace, including the caused by?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much. I fixed the problem by changing the configuration of spring data.
I set socket-timeout="1500" before. I should not set socket timeout. Defaults to 0 (infinite time).

Comment: Did that really help you?

Comment: I have the same issue even with set to 0